# GKMatchmakerViewController does not handle touches

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, game-center, gamekit, gkmatchmaker

I am showing this modalView and it does not handle touches. I am using cocos2d-iphone.

```
mControllerView= [[UIViewController alloc] init];
//mControllerView.view = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView];  
//this was the old method, it worked, but since ios6 it crashes

[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:mControllerView.view];

theClass = [[TheClass alloc] init: mControllerView]; 
// this shows the     GKMatchmakerViewController inside mControllerView
```

Comment: How did you implement the touch handling code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed cocos2d to a newer version, and didn't check what changed, or what should I refactor in the appDelegate. Now it works.